# Is λxyz.xz(yz) an abstraction or an application in Lambda Calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

According to the lambda calculus, should `λxyz.xz(yz)` be treated as the application of `λxyz.xz` to `(yz)` or do the brackets in `xz(yz)` simple mean that operations should go like `(xz)(yz)` rather than `((xz)y)z` and the entirety of `xz(yz)` is in the function "body" as it were?

I assume it's an abstraction and that the application would have to be written like `(λxyz.xz)yz` instead but my understanding is very poor so thought I'd check.

Comment: fyi this is also exactly the [S combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), one of the combinators needed to form the smallest turing-complete programming language :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. To be precise, it depends on the exact definition of the syntax of lambda terms, more precisely the rules for ommission of brackets, but there are convention for these rules. In particular, normally

- [application has precedence over
  abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55288291/6362033), so you
  first try to form the application of `xz` to `yz`, and only then the
  abstractions over `x`, `y` and `z`, rather than first forming the abstraction `λxyz.xz` and then embedding the resulting term in an applicatn to `yz` (which is what you would get if abstraction had precedence over application);
- bracketing in application terms is left-associative, so `xzyz` (without brackets around `yz`) would be read as `((xz)y)z`, and to indicate that `xz` is applied to `yz`, you need to bracket the term `yz`.

So as you suspect, `λxyz.xz(yz)` is a three-fold abstraction over `xz(yz)`, which is itself an application of `xz` to `yz`, which are again applications of `x` to `z` and `y` to `z`, repsectively.

With all brackets present, the term is `λx.(λy.(λz.(xz(yz))))`.
A syntax tree for the term thus looks as follows:

```
λxyz.xz(yz): abstraction
|- x: variable
|- λyz.xz(yz): abstraction
  |- y: variable
  |- λz.xz(yz): abstraction
     |- z: variable
     |- xz(yz): application
        |- xz: application
        |  |- x: variable
        |  |- z: variable
        |- yz: application
           |- y: variable
           |- z: variable
```

And as you also correctly suspected, the application of `λxyz.xz` to `yz` would be written as `(λxyz.xz)yz`.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help! :)